# Define a static IP for a managed VM

Tags: google-app-engine

As in the title, I'd like to deploy a managed VM attaching a static IP.

I don't want an IP for the instance lifetime, but I'd like to use the same IP every time the instance is recreated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to switch the VM instance to "user-managed" to assign a static IP address.

Comment: How are you supposed to run a web server like NodeJS from a Managed VM then? It allows me to set a static IP, but then later the instance is restarted and the IP changes but the static IP isn't updated to stay with the new instance. Is there some documentation on this?

Comment: I believe that more often than not, using a Managed VM is for when you want App Engine's scalability but a little more control of the host environment, so most users use a Load Balancer or address the instances via the appspot domain / custom domain in combination with default module / version. It seems possible that such a use-case of maintaining Managed VMs with staic IPs past restarts had escaped notice, and you should open an issue report in the [public issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-appengine/issues/list) to get this addressed.

Comment: OK, thank you. Issue opened: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12244